# Django. Retrieving data from a related model for use in a form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

How can I automatically associate a user with an id_ ticket and fill in a field in the form?

Sample form - https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YMUv.png

models.py

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    ticket_id = models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')
    ticket_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ticket_date_open = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='User')

class TicketMessage(models.Model):
    ticket_mes = models.TextField(verbose_name='Message')
    ticket = models.ForeignKey(Ticket, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

forms.py

```
class TicketMessageForm(ModelForm):
    ticket_mes = forms.CharField(label='Answer', required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = TicketMessage
        fields = ('ticket_mes', 'ticket')
```

views.py

```
class Ticket(DetailView, CreateView):
    model = Ticket
    form_class = TicketMessageForm
    ticket_message = TicketMessage
    template_name = 'support/ticket.html'
    context_object_name = 'one_ticket'
    allow_empty = False


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['ticket_message'] = TicketMessage.objects.filter()
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.user = self.request.user
        return super(Ticket, self).form_valid(form)

    success_url = reverse_lazy('ticket_list')
```

I assume that need to somehow take the data from the template and pass it to form_valid.

Tried adding a hidden field where passed the necessary information. This is works, but it looks wrong and unsafe.

```
<select class="d-none" name="ticket" required="" id="id_ticket">
<option value="{{ one_ticket.ticket_id }}" selected="">{{ one_ticket.ticket_id }}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: But you are getting the user in your ```form_valid```, aren't you? However, you need to save ```obj```.

Comment: I don't need a user, but a ticket id.

Comment: The ```self.get_object()``` method in your view gives you the current Ticket instance from which you can fetch the ticket_id